# Authenticate a site

Tags: web-part, authentication

I have a sharepoint site where on click of a certain image in a webpart will get redirected to another PHP Site.

Now i want to send the data from sharepoint site to PHP site in encrypted form so that the PHP site can authenticate the users.

How can  this be done?

Please help

Comment: Are you needing PHP code to authenticate users or do you have that already?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to do a form submit.

http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/form-submit/javascript-form-submit-image-2.html

```
<form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">
<img src="go.gif" width="33" height="19" border="0" />
</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    if(document.myform.onsubmit &&
    !document.myform.onsubmit())
    {
        return;
    }
 document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

This codeplex solution looks promising also.

https://sharepointformsubmit.codeplex.com/

Comment: How is this related to authenticating the user?

Comment: The question asked how "to send the data from sharepoint site to PHP site in encrypted form"

I don't think it was expected for me to write the PHP authentication code. Am I wrong?

Comment: The question do mention "authenticate the users"

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement some level of Single sign on. This can be accomplished by using an OpenID Identity Provider Security Token Service (IP-STS) like ADFS, identity server, live id, several others. When set up propertly both SharePoint and your PHP site rely on the IP-STS for authentication purposes and you get single sign on. Kind of like Stackexchange and Stackoverflow both rely on google, facebook, etc for authentication. Then you can use Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to post data from one site to the other.

It's pretty simple to connect SharePoint to an STS. You PHP site may not be so simple.